# Liquibase not running on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, liquibase

I have a project and in this project I use liquibase.
I'm now using Ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to run "liquibase update" inside the liquibase folder of the project in the terminal, I receive the message "liquibase: command not found".

I didn't find any instructions on how to configure liquibase on Ubuntu so that it will work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

2 methods are there:

1. Update the `PATH` variable with location of `liquibase` executable.
   Then run `liquibase update`
   `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir/liquibase/executable`
2. go to directory containing `liquibase` executabel and run `./liquibase update`

Comment: How can I update the path variable?
I get it working by using java -jar liquibase.jar update

Comment: I have added an example for updating PATH variable

Answer (score 1):

After a long while of searching and analyzing the problem I finally found the solution, which is kind of similar to what skr has written.

1. Download the Liquibase archive from official site.
2. Unpack it and put it where you want. I've chosen `/opt/` directory. Why `/opt/`? Here's the answer: [When installing user applications, where do “best practices” suggest they be located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/when-installing-user-applications-where-do-best-practices-suggest-they-be-loc)
3. Update the `PATH` variable with location of `liquibase` executable. There are great answers on [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)
   In my case, I included the `/opt/liquibase-bin/` directory, like this:
   `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/liquibase/dir`
   in my case: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/liquibase`

Now I can simply run Liquibase in terminal using just `liquibase` command.